# How to determine variable b

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 2 lines below here:

L1:(x,y,z) = t(2,-1,1)+(1,2,-3)

L2:(x,y,z) = t(-1,1,2)+(2b,3,2)

And the question is that for which b value where does these 2 lines intersect each others?

I know that you can use this like L1 = L2 to calculate the intersection but after that i am lost does someone knows how to set up the equation to solve this?

Thanks in Forward

Comment: Hint: The $t$ in those two formulae is *not necessarily the same $t$*. Rename it (say, to $s$) in one of them. Then equate the co-ordinates, you should end up with a system of equations in $t, s$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the cross product between the two direction vectors.

$n = (2,-1, 1) \times (-1, 1, 2) = (-3 , -5, 1 ) $

Now write down the equation of the plane passing the point $(1,2,-3)$ and having
a normal vector $n$, this equation is

$ -3( x-1) - 5 (x - 2) + (z + 3) = 0 $

Finally substitute the point $(2b,3,2)$ into the equation of the above plane and solve
for $b$

$ -3 (2 b - 1) - 5 (3 - 2) + (2 + 3) = 0 $

This simplifies to

$ -6 b + 3  = 0 $

Therefore, $b = \dfrac{1}{2} $

Comment: How did you think out this i got the same answer but in a different way?

Comment: I found the plane that contains $L_1$ and parallel to $L_2$, then made the distance between $(2b,3,2)$ and this plane $0$.